# XSLT: Use child node parameter to create column headers and populate column with respective data

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm rather new with XSLT and XPATH. I'm trying to parse all RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER values and generate a column for every unique value (duplicates removed). Then the idea for every ROW is to write EXECUTION_STATUS_NAME on column that corresponds with the column header.

XML:

```
<Report>
<RESULTS>
    <ROW>
        <TEST_RUN_ID>338</TEST_RUN_ID>
        <TEST_CASE_ID>202</TEST_CASE_ID>
        <NAME>Test Case 1</NAME>
        <EXECUTION_STATUS_NAME>Failed</EXECUTION_STATUS_NAME>
        <RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER>1.0.1</RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <TEST_RUN_ID>340</TEST_RUN_ID>
        <TEST_CASE_ID>202</TEST_CASE_ID>
        <NAME>Test Case 1</NAME>
        <EXECUTION_STATUS_NAME>Failed</EXECUTION_STATUS_NAME>
        <RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER>1.0.2</RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <TEST_RUN_ID>342</TEST_RUN_ID>
        <TEST_CASE_ID>202</TEST_CASE_ID>
        <NAME>Test Case 1</NAME>
        <EXECUTION_STATUS_NAME>Passed</EXECUTION_STATUS_NAME>
        <RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER>2.0.1</RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <TEST_RUN_ID>349</TEST_RUN_ID>
        <TEST_CASE_ID>202</TEST_CASE_ID>
        <NAME>Test Case 1</NAME>
        <EXECUTION_STATUS_NAME>Passed</EXECUTION_STATUS_NAME>
        <RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER>2.0.1</RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <TEST_RUN_ID>352</TEST_RUN_ID>
        <TEST_CASE_ID>202</TEST_CASE_ID>
        <NAME>Test Case 1</NAME>
        <EXECUTION_STATUS_NAME>Failed</EXECUTION_STATUS_NAME>
        <RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER>2.0.2</RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <TEST_RUN_ID>341</TEST_RUN_ID>
        <TEST_CASE_ID>203</TEST_CASE_ID>
        <NAME>Test Case 2</NAME>
        <EXECUTION_STATUS_NAME>Failed</EXECUTION_STATUS_NAME>
        <RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER>1.0.2</RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <TEST_RUN_ID>343</TEST_RUN_ID>
        <TEST_CASE_ID>203</TEST_CASE_ID>
        <NAME>Test Case 2</NAME>
        <EXECUTION_STATUS_NAME>Passed</EXECUTION_STATUS_NAME>
        <RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER>2.0.1</RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <TEST_RUN_ID>350</TEST_RUN_ID>
        <TEST_CASE_ID>203</TEST_CASE_ID>
        <NAME>Test Case 2</NAME>
        <EXECUTION_STATUS_NAME>Passed</EXECUTION_STATUS_NAME>
        <RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER>2.0.1</RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <TEST_RUN_ID>351</TEST_RUN_ID>
        <TEST_CASE_ID>203</TEST_CASE_ID>
        <NAME>Test Case 2</NAME>
        <EXECUTION_STATUS_NAME>Failed</EXECUTION_STATUS_NAME>
        <RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER>2.0.1</RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER>
    </ROW>
    <ROW>
        <TEST_RUN_ID>353</TEST_RUN_ID>
        <TEST_CASE_ID>203</TEST_CASE_ID>
        <NAME>Test Case 2</NAME>
        <EXECUTION_STATUS_NAME>Passed</EXECUTION_STATUS_NAME>
        <RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER>2.0.2</RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER>
    </ROW>
</RESULTS>
</Report>
```

XSLT that I currently have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:key name="releases" match="ROW" use="RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER" />
  <xsl:template match="/RESULTS">
    <table class="DataGrid">
        <tr>
            <th>TEST RUN</th>
            <th>TEST CASE</th>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>STATUS</th>
            <xsl:for-each select="ROW[count(. | key('releases', RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER)[1]) = 1]">
                <xsl:sort select="RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER" order="ascending"/>
                <th><xsl:value-of select="RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER"/></th>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="ROW">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="TEST_RUN_ID"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="TEST_CASE_ID"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="NAME"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="EXECUTION_STATUS_NAME"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER"/></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output now looks like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table class="DataGrid">
            <tr>
                <th>TEST RUN</th><th>TEST CASE</th><th>NAME</th><th>STATUS</th><th>1.0.1</th><th>1.0.2</th><th>2.0.1</th><th>2.0.2</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>338</td><td>202</td><td>Test Case 1</td><td>Failed</td><td>1.0.1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>340</td><td>202</td><td>Test Case 1</td><td>Failed</td><td>1.0.2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>342</td><td>202</td><td>Test Case 1</td><td>Passed</td><td>2.0.1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>349</td><td>202</td><td>Test Case 1</td><td>Passed</td><td>2.0.1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>352</td><td>202</td><td>Test Case 1</td><td>Failed</td><td>2.0.2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>341</td><td>203</td><td>Test Case 2</td><td>Failed</td><td>1.0.2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>343</td><td>203</td><td>Test Case 2</td><td>Passed</td><td>2.0.1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>350</td><td>203</td><td>Test Case 2</td><td>Passed</td><td>2.0.1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>351</td><td>203</td><td>Test Case 2</td><td>Failed</td><td>2.0.1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>353</td><td>203</td><td>Test Case 2</td><td>Passed</td><td>2.0.2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Expected output looks like this (after removing STATUS column):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table class="DataGrid">
            <tr>
                <th>TEST RUN</th><th>TEST CASE</th><th>NAME</th><th>1.0.1</th><th>1.0.2</th><th>2.0.1</th><th>2.0.2</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>338</td><td>202</td><td>Test Case 1</td><td>Failed</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>340</td><td>202</td><td>Test Case 1</td><td></td><td>Failed</td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>342</td><td>202</td><td>Test Case 1</td><td></td><td></td><td>Passed</td><td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>349</td><td>202</td><td>Test Case 1</td><td></td><td></td><td>Passed</td><td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>352</td><td>202</td><td>Test Case 1</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>Failed</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>341</td><td>203</td><td>Test Case 2</td><td></td><td>Failed</td><td></td><td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>343</td><td>203</td><td>Test Case 2</td><td></td><td></td><td>Passed</td><td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>350</td><td>203</td><td>Test Case 2</td><td></td><td></td><td>Passed</td><td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>351</td><td>203</td><td>Test Case 2</td><td></td><td></td><td>Failed</td><td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>353</td><td>203</td><td>Test Case 2</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>Passed</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The ultimate goal is to remove TEST_RUN_ID and show only unique TEST_CASE_IDs where the most recent TEST_RUN_ID value determines which EXECUTION_STATUS_NAME is displayed for certain RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER. Then the output would look like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table class="DataGrid">
            <tr>
                <th>TEST CASE</th><th>NAME</th><th>1.0.1</th><th>1.0.2</th><th>2.0.1</th><th>2.0.2</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>202</td><td>Test Case 1</td><td>Failed</td><td>Failed</td><td>Passed</td><td>Failed</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>203</td><td>Test Case 2</td><td>Not Run</td><td>Failed</td><td>Failed</td><td>Passed</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I'm still stuck with how to write release on correct column. Please help me to find a rational approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can store the unique release version numbers once and then generate the corresponding columns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    exclude-result-prefixes="exsl"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="releases" match="ROW" use="RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER" />

    <xsl:variable name="unique-releases-rtf">
        <xsl:for-each select="//ROW[count(. | key('releases', RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:sort select="RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER"/>
        </xsl:for-each>     
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="unique-releases" select="exsl:node-set($unique-releases-rtf)/*"/>

    <xsl:template match="RESULTS">
        <table class="DataGrid">
            <tr>
                <th>TEST RUN</th>
                <th>TEST CASE</th>
                <th>NAME</th>
                <xsl:for-each select="$unique-releases">
                    <th><xsl:value-of select="."/></th>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ROW">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="TEST_RUN_ID"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="TEST_CASE_ID"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="NAME"/></td>
            <xsl:variable name="row" select="."/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$unique-releases">
                <td>
                    <xsl:if test="$row/RELEASE_VERSION_NUMBER = .">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$row/EXECUTION_STATUS_NAME"/>             
                    </xsl:if>
                </td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The only caveat is that XSLT 1.0 makes the variable a result tree fragment you need to convert to a node set first, I have used `exsl:node-set` to do that as it is the function supported in most XSLT 1.0 implementations, although for Microsoft MSXML or XslTransform you would need to use the `msxsl:node-set` instead.